# In flink how to set set parallelism of Joinstream

Tags: join, apache-flink

When use joinStream to join two stream
I can't set parallelism of joinStream and it always be 1

```
aStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AWatermarks())
    .keyBy(AStream::getKey)
    .join(bStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BWatermarks())
    .keyBy(BStream::getKey))
    .where(AStream::getKey).equalTo(BStream::getKey)
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30))).apply(new Joiner())
```

[image]

Is there any way to set parallelism of JoinStream

Answer (score 0):

Your data flow program looks odd, you have extra `keyby`s, which may confuse Flink. Could you try

```
    aStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AWatermarks())
        .join(bStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BWatermarks()))
        .where(AStream::getKey).equalTo(BStream::getKey)
        .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30))).apply(new Joiner());
```